# HTML Have items float in left, center and right in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I'm having some problems with my HTML, I have a footer on my website and in that footer I have three different options, to start off with, on the left I have small logos that are facebook, twitter and youtube. In the center I have the copyright text for my website and on the right I have another facebook twitter and youtube icons. This is the problem that I'm getting [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/4dmkrd), whenever I have the copyright there, the right side logos go out of the footer. Here are my codes:
**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
        <div id="footerwrapper" style="margin-top: 78px">
            <a href="<?php echo $config['twitter']; ?>"><div class="footer-twitter" style="float:left"></div></a>
            <a href="<?php echo $config['youtube']; ?>"><div class="footer-youtube" style="float:left"></div></a>
            <a href="<?php echo $config['facebook']; ?>"><div class="footer-facebook" style="float:left"></div></a>
            <center><div style="padding-top: 24px;">Copyright goes here</div></center>
            <a href="<?php echo $config['twitter']; ?>"><div class="footer-twitter"></div></a>
            <a href="<?php echo $config['youtube']; ?>"><div class="footer-youtube"></div></a>
            <a href="<?php echo $config['facebook']; ?>"><div class="footer-facebook"></div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer {
    margin-top: 40px;
    background: #21282e;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #b0b6be;
    font-size: 18px;
    position:relative;
}
#footerwrapper {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 70%;
}
.footer-twitter {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url('../img/icons/twitter.png');
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.footer-youtube {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url('../img/icons/youtube.png');
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.footer-facebook {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url('../img/icons/facebook.png');
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Have considered using a grid to make things nice and tidy?

Comment: Sugest you to use a bootstrap grid (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). You just need to link a css and javascript file and it will create you a columns autamatically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I really don't wanna use any external bootstraps for my website, I just want it to be a simple website. If you know how to fix this a simple way, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at your code and see that there are a lot of elements in it, that you don't need. So I rearranged the HTML code (simplified it).

```
<div id="footer">
    <p>
        <a class="icon footer-twitter" href="#">Twitter</a>
        <a class="icon footer-youtube" href="#">YouTube</a>
        <a class="icon footer-facebook" href="#>">Facebook</a>
    </p>
    <p>Copyright goes here</p>
    <p>
        <a class="icon footer-twitter" href="#">Twitter</a>
        <a class="icon footer-youtube" href="#">Youtube</a>
        <a class="icon footer-facebook" href="#">Facebook</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

And the CSS that comes with it:

```
#footer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background: #21282e;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 15%;
    color: #b0b6be;
    font-size: 18px;
    position:relative;
}
#footer p {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
}
#footer p:nth-child(2) { text-align: center; }
#footer p:nth-child(3) { text-align: right; }


.icon {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.footer-twitter {
    background: url('...');
}
.footer-youtube {
    background: url('...');
}
.footer-facebook {
    background: url('...');
}
```

What I've did is:

1. Take away the `#footerwrapper`, instead of that I gave `#footer` a padding on the left and right of 15%. Adding a `box-sizing: border-box` to it aswell makes sure that the defined width is inclusive padding (and border when set).
2. I've split the footer in three parts, using a `p` (semantically better then `div`) and give them all a `width: 33.33%`. The first automatically has a left alignment, the second will be centered and the last one on the right. Since all the paragraphs float, I gave the parent (`#footer`) a `overflow: auto` so it knows that there are floated items inside it, preventing them to flow out of the parent.
3. Instead of wrapping the links in a div, you can display them as inline-blocks directly. This way you don't need the extra (meaningless) div. I also add a description between the starting and end tag of the link, and made sure to hide the text.

You can find a demo here: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tdm6vg6u/).

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own grid system if you want

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footerwrapper" style="margin-top: 78px">
        <div class="footerside left">
            <a href="<?php echo $config['twitter']; ?>"><div class="footer-twitter left" ></div></a>
            <a href="<?php echo $config['youtube']; ?>"><div class="footer-youtube left" ></div></a>
            <a href="<?php echo $config['facebook']; ?>"><div class="footer-facebook left" ></div></a>
        </div>

        <div class="footermiddle left">
            <div style="text-align:center">Copyright goes here</div>
        </div>

        <div class="footerside right" style="width:30%;float:right;">
            <a href="<?php echo $config['twitter']; ?>"><div class="footer-twitter right"></div></a>
            <a href="<?php echo $config['youtube']; ?>"><div class="footer-youtube right"></div></a>
            <a href="<?php echo $config['facebook']; ?>"><div class="footer-facebook right"></div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer {
    margin-top: 40px;
    background: #21282e;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #b0b6be;
    font-size: 18px;
    position:relative;
}
#footerwrapper {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 70%;
}
.footer-twitter {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url('../img/icons/twitter.png');
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.footer-youtube {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url('../img/icons/youtube.png');
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.footer-facebook {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url('../img/icons/facebook.png');
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.footerside {
    width:30%;
}

.footermiddle {
    padding-top: 20px;
    width:40%;
}

.right {
    float:right;
}

.left {
    float:left;
}
```